# Cycle decomposition into disjoint cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra

In [this link here](https://planetmath.org/EveryPermutationHasACycleDecomposition) it says that a cycle be decomposed a product of disjoint cycles. However say you consider the element of $S_4$ (The symmetric group of order 24) given by

$(12)(13)(14) = (1432)$. How would you write this as a product of disjoint cycles? An element in $S_4$ is either of the form $(1),(12),(123),(12)(43)$ or $(1234)$. So looking at the last cycle type we can never decompose it into a disjoint cycle unless we have something like $(1)(234)$. However if you decompose it into the form $(1)(234)$ or say $(14)(23)$ would this not contradict it being of the last cycle type?

Comment: "... that a cycle can be decomposed into a product of disjoint cycles." No. What it says it that a **permutation** can be decomposed into a product of disjoint cycles. (A cycle can be decomposed into a product of disjoint cycles simply as itself).

Comment: The permutation $(1432)$ already is a product of disjoint cycles. In particular, one cycle is required to describe it.

Comment: @Ben: You cannot delete this post yourself (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that-actually-mean/5222#5222) for when a post can be deleted). The moderators *can* delete it for you, but at least in my opinion, this question *does* have value - if someone else has the same confusion, they can come to this page and learn from it. So I am loath to delete this question.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Thanks, we should keep the question then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$(1432)$ can be written as a product of disjoint cycles like so: $(1432)$. It's a product (with one factor) of disjoint cycles (each cycle in the product is disjoint from any *other* cycle in the product).

The main problem is that you misread the link. It doesn't say every *cycle* can be decomposed into a product of disjoint cycles, it says every **permutation** (on a finite set) can be decomposed into a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: The difference is subtle (between a permutation and a cycle) but I think I get it.

Comment: That being said could you elaborate on the difference between a permutation on a finite set and a cycle?

Comment: @D Lim: A permutation on a finite set $X$ is simply a bijection from $X$ to itself. A cycle is a particular kind of permutation, in which you have a subset $Y$ of objects, $Y=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, $n\geq 1$, and the cycle acts by mapping every object in $X-Y$ to itself, mapping $a_i$ to $a_{i+1}$ for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$, and mapping $a_n$ to $a_1$.

Answer (score 2):

$(1432)$ is already a cycle, so there is nothing to decompose. In the decomposition of $(1432)$ into disjoint cycles there is only one term: the cycle $(1432)$ itself. The theorem about the decomposition of an arbitrary element of $S_n$ as a product of disjoint cycles allows the possibility that there is only one cycle in the decomposition.

Comment: Right that's what I needed to know, that the possibility of only one cycle being in the decomposition is allowed.