# If two powers of permutations are equal and have no common symbols, they're the identity. - Mulholland p. 44 Proof to Theorem 4.2

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, intuition

Theorem 4.2 (Order of a Permutation): The order of a permutation written in disjoint cycle form is the least common multiple of the lengths of the cycles.

Proof: 
**One cycle:** As we noted above, a cycle of length m has order m. (See Exercise 9.)

**Two disjoint cycles:** Two disjoint cycles: Now suppose $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are disjoint cycles of lengths a and b. Let k be the least
common multiple of a and b, that is, k is the smallest positive integer which is divisible by both a and b. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$are disjoint cycles, hence they commute. Then $(\alpha\beta)^k = \alpha^k \beta^k = ee = e$. Here we used Lemma 3.4 and that fact that $\rho|k$ implies
$\rho^k = e$ for all permutations $\rho$.

It follows from Theorem 3.6 that the order of $\alpha\beta = |\alpha\beta|$divides $k$. We
now wish to show $|\alpha\beta|$ = k. From $e = (\alpha\beta)^{|\alpha\beta|} = \alpha^{|\alpha\beta|}\beta^{|\alpha\beta|} \iff \alpha^{-|\alpha\beta|} = \beta^{|\alpha\beta|}$. However, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ have no symbol
in common, and since raising a cycle to a power does not introduce new symbols, $\alpha^{-|\alpha\beta|}$ and $\beta^{|\alpha\beta|}$ also have no
symbol in common. Since $\alpha^{-|\alpha\beta|} = \beta^{|\alpha\beta|}$ and have no common symbols then they both must be the identity:
$\alpha^{-|\alpha\beta|} = \beta^{|\alpha\beta|} = e.$  If follows from Theorem 3.6 that $|\alpha\beta| $ is divisible by a and b. This means that k = lcm(a; b) must
also divide $|\alpha\beta| $ . Therefore $|\alpha\beta| $  = k, as desired.

Another explanation. Reference: Joseph Gallian p.102 in Contemporary Abs Algebra

[image]

**More than two disjoint cycle:** The general case involving more than two cycles is handled in an analogous
way.

> How does $\alpha^{-|\alpha\beta|} = \beta^{|\alpha\beta|} = e $ ? What's the intuition? I understand [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/56032):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If $\alpha,\beta$ are permutations of $X$ and $X=A\cup B$ is a disjoint union, and if
$$
\alpha|_A = \operatorname{id}_A \quad \beta|_B=\operatorname{id}_B
$$
then what happens if you restrict the relation
$$
1=(\alpha \beta)^n=\alpha^n \beta^n
$$
to $A$ or $B$?

*edit:*
$$
\operatorname{id}_A = \operatorname{id}_X|_A =(\alpha \beta)^n|_A
=\alpha|_A^n \beta|_A^n = \beta|_A^n
$$
but on $B$ you have $\beta|_B^n=\operatorname{id}_B$. So $\beta^n=1$, because it does nothing on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Can you please flesh out what you are trying to induce? My book doesn't talk about restrictions to permutations like you wrote. I don't understand.

Comment: Two disjoint cycles operate on disjoint subsets of $X=\{1,\dots,n\}$, the idea is that this implies $1=\alpha^n\beta^n \Rightarrow 1=\alpha^n$

Comment: Thanks. But can you plase flesh out the detals? I'm asking this because I don't understand how 'this implies' ?